# how to extract a particular string from a sentence present at any particular index in list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, spyder

```
names=['alex','peter','sana','alice']

info=['alex is working on os_10 coolest one',
'peter is working on OS_9 which is not that cool', 
'sana is working on OS_7 which is quite old', 
'Thanos is also using os_10', 
'alice is fan of thanos so she also uses os_10']
```

#i have tried

```
 v=[]

    for name in names:
        a= [x for x in info if name in x]
        #print(a)
        v.append(a)

    print(v)
```

fisrt I have made a list which contains only that person's info whose name is in the names list 
Now i want o/p like alex: os_10, peter: OS_9 etc

Comment: What have you tried? Please post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you want to extract the first and last word of the sentence in the list? What are the rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Split` the text and get the items *First* and *Last* index.

**Code:**

```
a = ['Alex is working on OS_10', 'Peter is working on OS_8', 'Sana is working on OS_7']
print(*[f"{t.split()[0]} {t.split()[-1]}" for t in a], sep=',\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Alex OS_10,
Peter OS_8,
Sana OS_7
```

Comment: suppose if names are stored in another list (say name['Alex','Sana','peter','Alice'] )and information given in list [a] do not contain fixed pattern (like if we don't know that OS is in [-1]) but we know that in name list there is a name which can/can't match that in list[a] and if it is matches then it should print corresponding name and OS used?

Comment: @DIWAKARMISHRA I didn’t quite get that clearly. Can you show the code piece that you’d tried? Also, you cannot expect others to write code for you; We can help in fixing problems you have.

Comment: hey i have modified can you please check that

Answer (score 2):

**Simply split by whitespace and get the first and last word.**

```
a = ['Alex is working on OS_10', 'Peter is working on OS_8', 'Sana is working on OS_7']

extracted_list = [(item.split()[0], item.split()[-1]) for item in a]

final_result = '\n'.join((f"{tuple[0]} {tuple[1]}" for tuple in extracted_list))

print(final_result)
```

Comment: using json is redundant

Comment: @prashantrana just to print the result

Comment: a simple print(*result,sep='\n') will do .

Comment: @prashantrana  suppose if names are stored in another list (say name['Alex','Sana','peter','Alice'] )and information given in list [a] do not contain fixed pattern (like if we don't know that OS is in [-1]) but we know that in name list there is a name which can/can't match that in list[a] and if it is matches then it should print corresponding name and OS used?

Comment: @DIWAKARMISHRA if you want to get OS and know OS is there not it's position then use`regular expression` to get result. rest if name in another list and you want to check that name in [a] or not then that's u can also do by checking eaach list if it's there or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, in this particular case, use slice to avoid splitting the string twice.

```
a = ['Alex is working on OS_10', 'Peter is working on OS_8', 'Sana is working on OS_7']
data = [ ' '.join(line.split()[::4]) for line in a ]

print(data)
['Alex OS_10', 'Peter OS_8', 'Sana OS_7']
```

You can adapt the slice to your needs knowing that it works this way

```
a_list[start_index : end_index : step]
```

See this for more information
https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Answer (score 0):

Get first word with `split()[0]` (split by whitespaces, and get the first one), and get the last word with `split()[-1]`.

```
v = [ s.split()[0] + " " + s.split()[-1] for s in a ]
```

Then you can join everything with `",\n"`

```
print( ",\n".join(v) )
```